# How do I force a www subdomain on both HTTPS and HTTP?

Tags: apache, htaccess, redirects, url-rewriting

For whatever reason I can’t seem to get this right. I’ve looked at many examples on here and on the Apache website. I’m trying to force `www.example.com` instead of example.com on **both** HTTP **and** HTTPS, but I am not trying to force use of HTTPS instead of HTTP.

The following code seems to work for all HTTPS connections, but will not cause a redirect for HTTP connections.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems right. But let me provide some checkpoints you can perform.

- Are HTTP and HTTPS set to point to the same physical directory?
- Have you tried asking on server fault?
- Can you try using modifiers to check like

Code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} = on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} != on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Yes they use the same file directory. I have not asked on server fault. I tried using the code you posted and got a 500 internal server error.

Comment: @Brian Perin: The StackExchange markup was messed up (I guess there's a bug in it when you try to follow a list directly with a code block). The `RewriteCond` s needed to be on separate lines.

Comment: "got a 500 internal server error" - the 500 error is caused by the incorrectly formatted _CondPatterns_: There should be no space after `=` in `= on` and `!= on`. It should be `=on` and `!=on` respectively. (Or omit the `=` altogether; it's not strictly required.)

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem, and the below solved it for me.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The first condition (that checks that the `Host` header is not empty) is not necessary, since the second condition checks that the `Host` header is a specific value. If the second condition is successful then the first condition must also be successful.